# How to get value when td clicked in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with html controls such as `a` `select`, etc.. Now when I click on `a` tag I want to get `span` value in `first` `td`

And I tried this:

```js
$('tr > td a').on('click', function(e) {
  alert($(this).parent().find('td').eq(0).find('span').html());
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th {
  width: 750px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  align: centre
}
select, a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Clicks</th>
    <th>Clicks2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="span1">Hi!</span>
      <a href="#">Save</a>
    </td>
    <td style="block">
      <a href="#" class="Click" id="click1">Click Me</a>
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="Click" id="click2">Click Me</a>
      <select>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/462640us/)

I tried to show `popup` only when `a` is clicked but it is poping up every time `td` is clicked.

So I gave `a` tag a class `Click` and tried to achieve the same but couldn't.

How to show popup only when `a` clicked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Any code related to your question must be **in** your question, not linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to follow some random link to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: I've moved your fiddle code into the question per the above. You might want to check that I've done so correctly.

Comment: when you click `a` tag of first `td` or `a` tag of any `td`? if for any `a` tag then you can write this `alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).find('span').html());` find closest `tr` and then find first `td` and then `span` inside it.. Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/462640us/4/)**

Comment: hi are you want to try this http://jsfiddle.net/462640us/3/

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` is `display:block` so it maintains the whole space of the `td`. Give your a `display:inline-block`. This will let the `a` take only the space it needs. And then your clickhandler will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the javascript function onclick="functionname()" inside your 'a' tag and write your popup code in that function.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
$('tr > td a').on("click"...
```

adds a click handler to the `a`, then the `this` inside is the `a`, so

```
$(this).parent()
```

gives the td

followed by

```
.find('td')
```

will try to find a `td` inside the `td`, which won't happen

To get the first `td` use `closest` which goes up the parents until if find the target, ie:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').find('span').html()
```

or

```
$("td:first > span", $(this).closest('tr')).html()
```

(or `.eq(0)` if you don't like `:first`)

Answer (score 0):

You could asign a class to the span in your first column, say `myClass`, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Clicks</th>
        <th>Clicks2</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="myClass" id = "span1">Hi!</span>
        <a href="#">Save</a>
    </td>
    <td style="block">
        <a href="#" class="Click" id="click1">Click Me</a>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="Click" id="click2">Click Me</a>
         <select>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

,and use jQuery like this:

```
 $('td > a').on('click', function (e) {
     alert($(this).parents('tr').find(".myClass").html());
 });
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uorar9x6/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change you script from this

```
$(function(){
    $('tr > td a').on('click', function(e) {
      alert($(this).parent().find('td').eq(0).find('span').html());
    });
});
```

To this

```
$(function () {
    $('tr > td a').on('click', function (e) {
        alert($(this).parent().find('span').html());
    });
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/hdzswrn7/